# How to use the ZXING scan result

Tags: android, zxing

I'm breaking my head over this one. I'm kind of new in android development.

I want to use the scan result from ZXING. I integrated ZXING into my android app, the scan works ok. Now I want to use the scan result to update a TextView in the main activity.

How can I do that?

My code is doing the following for now:

1. Open Main activity with a button.
2. On clicking the button it activates the scanner.
3. After scanning it goes back to the main activity.
4. The TextView is empty and for some reason it goes back to the original content after moving from landscape to portrait.

After (2) I want to use the scanned result to update the TextView in the main activity (tv in my code).

Please help guys,
Thanks.

My code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button pressToScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    pressToScan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent data = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            data.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(data, 0);

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanResult);
                tv.setText(data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
        }
    });
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String contents = null;
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0) {
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
             String format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");

             // Handle successful scan
          } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
             // Handle cancel
          }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Store the scanned info in locally and retrieve where ever you want.

Comment: Can you explain for me how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the following block

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanResult);
tv.setText(data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));
```

to

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
String contents = null;
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 0) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
         String format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
         //moved here
         TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scanResult);
         tv.setText(contents);
         // Handle successful scan
      } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         // Handle cancel
      }
}
```

}

[Edit]

Add this in your activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

in the manifest change the main activity to add android:configChanges="orientation"

```
<activity android:name="..."
          android:label="@string/appName"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: I tried that, and it works only when I'm on landscape. When I change to portrait on the device the text disappears. Thanks for the fast respond by the way :)

Comment: you have to include android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" this in your manifest file. so that whenever the orientation has been changed, it will never reload the application.

Comment: That works great! Thank you. Do you know how can I send the "contents" to another Activity?

Comment: Got it, I forgot to add the second activity to my Manifest.

Answer (score 1):

when you call `startActivityForResult()` when the called activity sets it's data , it calls `onActivityResult()` in your activity, `startActivityForResult()` doesn't suspend execution of method , so the correct way to write this

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
String contents = null;
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 0) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
         String format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
         tv.setText(contents);

         // Handle successful scan
      } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
         // Handle cancel
      }
}

}

}
```

Comment: Note that when you switch orientation the `onCreate()` is called so you need to store the last read data and retrieve it in `onCreate()`

Comment: @Ohadza to send contents to other activity use `putExtras()` on the intent that call the other activity which take key , value pair , check here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: I knew that, but stupid me didn't add the Second Activity to the Manifest. Thank's for your help man!